# Prepared statements: Fetch as array

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a query like this:

```
$stmt = $cxn->prepare('SELECT post_id, user_id, content, datetime, total_comments, total_likes FROM posts WHERE user_id = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($post_id, $user_id, $content, $datetime, $total_comments, $total_likes);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
```

I'd like to instead just have the results put directly into an array. How can I change my code to reflect that (PHP and MySQLi)?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please specify what language this is?

Answer (score 0):

For a normal array (indexed by numbers), you can use
`$stmt->fetch_array()`
That will look like this:
`[ ['x', 'y'], ['a', 'b'] ]`

When you need associative arrays, this will do:
`$stmt->fetch_assoc()`
and it will look like this:
`[ ['field1' => 'x', 'field2' => 'y'], ['field1' => 'a', 'field2' => 'b'] ]`

Comment: `Warning: mysqli_stmt::fetch() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given`

Comment: Oh, I thought you were using PDO. Sorry. I will adit the answer to MySQLi

Comment: I'm getting `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_array()` now.